# Terminating FFMPEG from Python using Linux

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, subprocess

So I have a project that listens for button inputs in Python, and records video from a camera and an external microphone once a certain button is pressed, now when I want to stop recording, I press another button and stop recording on my camera and the microphone, and then I call ffmpeg using the subprocess module:

```
mergeFiles = subprocess.Popen("sudo ffmpeg -i /home/pi/Video/video.mov -i /home/pi/Audio/test.wav -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest /media/pi/USB/Output/output.mkv", shell=True)
```

to merge the audio and video files I just created.

Now once I call ffmpeg, it doesn't stop until I send the process a signal interrupt from the keyboard... is there a way to either have the process stop as soon as it's done merging, or to automatically terminate/kill ffmpeg after a certain amount of time?

I have read up on other posts like this and none of the solutions work for me. I can't kill the process using the PID because every time I look up ffmpeg's PID, it is a different ID, and calling something like
    mergeFiles.kill()
doesn't work for me.

Comment: mergeFiles.kill() doesn't work because of the supproccess command was called by the root user. Try changing the permission of ffmpeg to allow regular users or run your entire script using the sudo user

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't stop

Comment: which one did you try ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried not calling ffmpeg as root, by simply omitting "sudo", and using mergeFiles.kill() still didn't kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it is doing this is because the ffmpeg command starts a second process and you don't have the Pid of the second process (just a guess I am not an expert).

My Solution was to call `pkill ffmpeg` as a subprocess when I want to terminate ffmpeg. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill).